# Question about derivations of "CS231N Backpropagation gradient"

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, neural-networks

There is a great explanation of the calculation of backpropagation gradient in the CS231n class. Please find the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202549/cs231n-backpropagation-gradient/2225404).

[twolffpiggott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/146728/twolffpiggott)'s answer improved my general understanding. However, I've got stuck at one of the derivations. My first question is about this formula:

$$  \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}_i}{\partial \boldsymbol{w_j}} = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}_i}{\partial f_k} \times \frac{\partial f_k}{\partial \boldsymbol{w_j}} .$$

How do you convert into the second line, which is: 
$$ \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}_i}{\partial f_j} \times \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial \boldsymbol{w_j}}$$
In other words, how did $\sum$ turned into the second line?

The second question is about $k$. May I kindly ask, what is $k$ in those lines? Is it different from $j$?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the answer you mention the sum disappears because among all the $f_k$ only $f_j$ depends on $w_j$. Therefore, for $k \neq j$, $\dfrac{\partial f_k}{\partial w_j}=0$.

$k$ and $j$ are indices, they can be considered as "mute", because they do not represent anything. You can write the same equations with $k$ replaced by $j$ and $j$ replaced by $k$. However we *usually* like using $k$ for summation and $j$ as a particular index, but that is only a choice.