# Backward propagation math: where does -1 come from?

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to understand the math of [CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/) as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202549/cs231n-backpropagation-gradient) and implemented [here](https://zhangruochi.com/cs231n-assignment1/2019/10/01/).

To start, I dont get where the `-1` operation come from as seen in `Softmax.softmax_loss_vectorized()` line `87`:

```
86      dS = softmax_output.copy()
87      dS[range(num_train), list(y)] += -1
88      dW = (X.T).dot(dS)
89      dW = dW/num_train + reg* W
```

And in `TwoLayerNet.softmax_loss_vectorized()` line `125`:

```
124     dscores = softmax_output.copy()
125     dscores[range(N), list(y)] -= 1
126     dscores /= N
127     grads['W2'] = h_output.T.dot(dscores) + reg * W2
128     grads['b2'] = np.sum(dscores, axis = 0)
129     
130     dh = dscores.dot(W2.T)
131     dh_ReLu = (h_output > 0) * dh
132     grads['W1'] = X.T.dot(dh_ReLu) + reg * W1
133     grads['b1'] = np.sum(dh_ReLu, axis = 0)
```

If explanation for subsequent operations could be given, that would be wonderful.  I could not make a one-to-one match with aforementioned [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202549/cs231n-backpropagation-gradient).  Thank you so much in advance.

PS: the code is in Python.

========================================================================

More info:

I think the answer to `-1` is in section `Computing the Analytic Gradient with Backpropagation` of this [link](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/).

This [link](https://gitlab.com/me-learnz/CS231n/blob/master/assignment1/cs231n/classifiers/neural_net.py) provides the following graph for the two-layer case:

```
# W1
# ----+                      W2         b2
# dW1  \                     ----+      ----+
#      (*)----+              dW2  \     db2  \
# X    /       \                   \          \  
# ----+         \               h   \          \   scores           softmaxes
#               (+)------(ReLU)-----(*)--------(+)--------(softmax)----------
# b1            /  drelu        dh      dscores    dscores 
# -------------+
# db1
```

This [link](https://xiandong79.github.io/cs231n-Backpropagation) and this [link](https://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/) offer much better visualization, like the one below.

[image: img]

I still dont get how that graph come about, and what are the equations leading to the code implemented above.

Comment: These are two different ways of decreasing dS or dscores by 1. You can either add -1 or subtract 1.

Comment: Which language do you use ?

Comment: @JeanMarie that is pretty clearly python for a number of reasons, but the clearest of which is the usage of `np` which is the traditional shorthand for numPy... `import numpy as np`, a standard library to import which handles a number of menial math and arithmetic related functions.

Comment: @tomi, I get that.  What I dont get is why it must be done?  Which equation does that come from?

Comment: @JMoravitz I guessed it, but you are mentionning things that aren't in the main text... I think that a self-contained question displaying code should at least mention the used language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where does -1 come from?

From the first [link](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/), we're given $\mathcal{L}_i = - \log\left(p_{y_i}\right)$ and $p_{y_i} = \frac{e^{f_{y_i}}}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{f_j}}.$ It follows (by the chain rule$^\dagger$) that $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}_i}{\partial f_k} = p_k - \mathbb{1}_{y_i=k}.$ The lines of NumPy code that you're asking about simply appear to be implementing the latter equation.

---

$^\dagger$ The chain rule gives

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}_i}{\partial f_k}
&=\sum_l\left( \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}_i}{\partial p_l}\frac{\partial p_l}{\partial f_k}\right)\\[5mm]
&=\sum_l\left( \left(-p_l^{-1}\mathbb{1}_{l=y_i}\right)\left({e^{f_l}\mathbb{1}_{k=l}\over\sum_{j=1}^K e^{f_j}}-{e^{f_l}e^{f_k}\over\left(\sum_{j=1}^K e^{f_j}\right)^2}\right)\right)\\[5mm]
&=\sum_l\left( \left(-p_l^{-1}\mathbb{1}_{l=y_i}\right)\left({p_l\mathbb{1}_{k=l}}-{p_l p_k}\right)\right)\\[5mm]
&=\sum_l\left( \left(-\mathbb{1}_{l=y_i}\right)\left({\mathbb{1}_{k=l}}-{ p_k}\right)\right)\\[5mm]
&=p_k-\mathbb{1}_{y_i=k}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you so much.